# how to know from which class a method of another class is called in odoo

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-10

I have 2 models

- 1: example.orderline
- 2: product.product

which are in separate classes

there is a many2one field "stock" in example.orderline 
stock=fields.Many2one("product.product","Product")

I want to override `name_get` method of model "product.product" for field "stock"
which I did successfully:

```
def name_get(self):
     result = []
     for record in self:
        default_code = record.default_code
        result.append((record.id, default_code))

    return result
```

But the above also applies to Sale order and purchase order.
how to name get method only applies for example.orderline model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `context` attribute in `example.orderline` model view side to handle mentioned situation.

For example:

```
<field name="stock" context="{'display_my_name': True}"/>
```

Now check context value in `name_get()` method. If we find our context key, execute our custom logic, otherwise return super.

For example:

```
def name_get(self):
    if 'display_my_name' in self._context and self._context.get('display_my_name')
        result = []
        for record in self:
            default_code = record.default_code
            result.append((record.id, default_code))
        return result
    else:
        return super(YourClass, self).name_get()
```

In this way, it will not disturb other form view field value display.